# Formatting multiple place name to single name

Tags: java

In google API, multiple people rename his spot. Someone giving prefecture name as `"Tokyo"`, `"tokyo"`, `"TOKYO"`, `"tokyo 2"` etc.

Is there any library to make it in a single format like, always it will give **"TOKYO"**

Actually, I can write my own method, but searching for an existing library.

Advance thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Well, just turning strings with different capitalization to all-uppercase is fairly easy with the `toUpperCase()` method of `String`.  But what would be the criteria for deciding that something like "Tokyo 2" really means just "Tokyo" (and thus "TOKYO")?  Should we be able to figure out that, say, "Los Angles Metro Area" is actually "LOS ANGELES"?

Comment: @KevinAnderson, Thanks. Actually I want that type of existing scrapping library. For that reason, I posted this question.